# spacing above the navigation bar, occurs when using headings and paragraphing

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to get the space off the navigation bar, but i don't know what's the problem. The codes work when there isn't any headings or paragraphing

**Demo**:  http://jsfiddle.net/n89s25q6/

html

`<div id="content">
    <h2>Content</h2>
</div>`

Thanks for the help

Comment: possibly a clearfix issue, add overflow:hidden to #wrapper, and see how it goes; also remove that height: 0px from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `nav` element is floated, and the next element contains the `h2` element, which has margin by default.

To fix it, you can:

- Clear the float:

  ```css
  #content {
      clear: left; /* or `clear: both` */
  }
  ```
- Remove the margin:

  ```css
  #content > h2 {
      margin: 0;
  }
  ```
- Remove the float:

  ```css
  #headernav {
      float: none; /* default value */
  }
  ```
- Prevent margin collapse, e.g. with

  ```css
  #content > h2 {
      display: inline-block;
  }
  ```